# Typing first parameter in a typescript function based on the second optional parameter

Tags: typescript, function, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I'm working on a state manager library for React, I wanted to add a helper function which would allow users to set deeply nested states easily from outside of React with the use of a selector and so far the helper function looks something like this:

```js
type NestedStateSetter<State> = <Selected = State>(
    update: Selected | (() => Selected) | (() => Promise<Selected>),
    selector?: (state: State) => Selected
) => Promise<Selected>;

const initialState = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 0,
        },
    },
};

const setState: NestedStateSetter<typeof initialState> = (update, selector) => {
    throw "Yeet"
};

setState(1, (state) => state.a.b.c) // Ok
setState(() => 2, (state) => state.a.b.c) // Ok
setState(async () => 5, (state) => state.a.b.c) // Not ok
```

But the third call to 'setState' is giving us this error on the `(state) => state.a.b.c` of the third call above:

> Argument of type '(state: { a: { b: { c: number; }; }; }) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { a: { b: { c: number; }; }; }) => Promise'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.(2345)

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDKwCGTUWEgTgDzpYQB8UAvFMRADYQDGSyVUJSZAFAFBT9QArmGSkAXO3pMWUAD5QuXAJRUKOBsxQr5ilZQoAFfAHsAtgEt4EWhpZklAGj4Crt4-gD8EronHtMSHpqUprIPEFQRmaW1urSKGQA3Dw8jMYAdohQ5unmwOYYdBzQ1ADezvwYEuUCtVAARtUVdbWMEgAMTi38AL5dAn08PcmpGVlWwMUScIgoxTh4EESgkMYAZtm5+YXFFNRcwqJIDlCu0u4RNQLAABYmAO5QAEQAmhC4T0MjE8VcAIwnHwBCARXxIAB0GHB9XBjBUAHp4VAAPIAax4P2BulUUAATICwSCcYTIdDYQikWiMbhfhh4CB0owFBEAKwE4Gg4GkmFwqCI2DGYBQYyooA)

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3xtcua?file=index.ts)

I tried to use a curried function but that would be a breaking change and I would rather avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: What, in words, are the rules by which you want the first parameter typed in relation to the second? And is your "Not ok" call at the end meant to be valid? What would an invalid call look like?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, the goal was to just make the third call to setState valid without losing types in the process, answer from Robby Cornelissen worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75659282/14306019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order the types in your union from most specific to least specific to prevent TypeScript from matching the first, most generic type.

So, instead of:

```
update: Selected | (() => Selected) | (() => Promise<Selected>)
```

Use:

```
update: (() => Promise<Selected>) | (() => Selected) | Selected
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```
type NestedStateSetter<State> = <Selected = State>(
  update: (() => Promise<Selected>) | (() => Selected) | Selected,
  selector?: (state: State) => Selected
) => Promise<Selected>;

const initialState = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 0,
    },
  },
};

const setState: NestedStateSetter<typeof initialState> = (update, selector) => {
  throw 'Yeet';
};

setState(1, (state) => state.a.b.c); // Ok
setState(
  () => 2,
  (state) => state.a.b.c
); // Ok
setState(
  async () => 5,
  (state) => state.a.b.c
); // Ok
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDKwCGTUWEgTgDzpYQB8UAvFMRADYQDGSyVUJSZAFAFBRQBXMMlIAuKFy4BKKhQAK+APYBbAJbwItBsxRkZAHwnTZ7ekxYHT2lgBo+UDdcX4A-OK6Ix7TEhmUKONYoPH7ySmoaWua6ANw8PIyKAHaIUKpJqsCqGHQc0NQA3vYY4kX8-ABGpfblUIziAAx2tQC+zVBtPC1xCcmpGsB54nCIKHk4eBBEoJCKAGZpGVk5eRTUXEIiSDYOZszOoVBlUMAAFkoA7lAA5ACaELjXcd3xA3lcAIw7Hj4Qh55IAB0GEBFUBjCkMSgAHpoVAAPIAax4b1+vH4xn8UAATO0fqR-r9gaDwSEobCEcjUaR0VAMPAQElGBJDgBWPEAv4mTnEsGMMkwuFIoA)</sup>

Comment: Hmm, this works, but when we don't give it a selector, the 'setState' function allows any type to be passed in the place of the initialState, e.g: setState("some random string"), ideally we want to default to 'typeof initialState' if the selector is not provided, but i think this will be either very difficult / impossible... in that case i will just implement a new function specifically for this case.